# Getting the sum of a value for two seperate date ranges in a single MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a table similar to the following:

```
|id|empID|date      |tTime|
| 1|   42|2013-08-04|    8|
| 2|   42|2013-08-05|    8|
| 3|   42|2013-08-06|    8|
| 4|   42|2013-08-11|    8|
| 5|   42|2013-08-12|    8|
| 6|   43|2013-08-04|    7|
| 7|   43|2013-08-05|    7|
| 8|   43|2013-08-06|    7|
| 9|   43|2013-08-11|    7|
|10|   43|2013-08-12|    7|
```

For purposes of this question the table structure would be:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `empID` int(8) default NULL,
  `date` date default NULL,
  `tTime` decimal(16,8) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

*The real table is more involved bu the column types and other details are the same.*

I need to know `SUM(tTime)` for each `empID` for two different date ranges (08/04/13 -> 08/10/13 and 08/11/13 -> 08/17/13 in this case).  My goal is to end up with something along the lines of:

```
|empID|  A|  B|
|   42| 24| 16|
|   43| 21| 14|
```

*In this case the date ranges are weeks but that is not always the case so the date ranges need to be flexible.*

**So far I am doing this with two queries**.  I'd like to be able to do it in one if that is possible/more efficient.

```
SELECT `empID`, SUM(`tTime`) FROM `table` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2013-08-04' AND '2013-08-10' GROUP BY `empID`;
SELECT `empID`, SUM(`tTime`) FROM `table` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2013-08-11' AND '2013-08-17' GROUP BY `empID`;
```

Which gets me:

```
|empID|SUM(`tTime`)|
|   42|          24|
|   43|          21|
```

and

```
|empID|SUM(`tTime`)|
|   42|          16|
|   43|          14|
```

Is the most efficient way for me to get the results I am looking for or is there a better way to be doing this?

Comment: Can you also post the table create structure and information about storage engine in use?

Comment: yes, group by is the best way for this requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to get the result:

```
SELECT `empID`
     , SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-08-04' AND '2013-08-10',`tTime`,0)) AS A
     , SUM(IF(`date` BETWEEN '2013-08-11' AND '2013-08-17',`tTime`,0)) AS B
  FROM `table`
 WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2013-08-04' AND '2013-08-17'
 GROUP BY `empID`;
```

The "trick" is using an expression with a conditional test, and returning tTime or 0 depending on the result of the test.

This is usually more efficient than two separate statements, it's one pass through the data, and one GROUP BY operation.

Comment: Nice "trick" indeed +1 if you index KEY(date, empID) it should be faster indeed. (sure would help if the engine was InnoDB but it's MyISAM)

Comment: @Raymond Nijland: an index `ON(empID,date)` might actually make it even faster for a large set (depending on the data distribution), if MySQL makes use of the index to optimize the GROUP BY operation and avoid a "Using filesort" operation.) An `EXPLAIN` would show the access plan.

Comment: indeed that would make sense then a "loose index scan" could be used.

Comment: A "covering index" might get even better performance ... `on t (empid, date, ttime)`.  We'd expect the output from EXPLAIN to show "Using index", and for "Using filesort" to be absent.  With that index added, an index on just `(empid,date)` would be redundant, so it should be dropped.